# Triggering a local poetry reinstall on dependency update

Tags: python-poetry

Right now, if a dependency changes, I need the code to fail for me to notice and run a `poetry install`. Is there a better way to do this?
Ideally, when I run poetry and the `pyproject.toml` doesn't match what's installed I'd like it to notice and either warn me or go ahead and update package versions.

Comment: what is the scenario when a dependency changes? How does it happen if not via Poetry?

Comment: Someone else adds a dep, and you pull the updated code version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to update your local virtualenv with poetry, whenever you checkout a branch with (possibly) modified poetry lock files.

This can be done with a [git post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout), which runs whenever you check out a branch, or pulling in new commits.

To configure it to run a `poetry install --sync`, you need to create (or modify an existing) file `.git/hooks/post-checkout` (with +x):

```
#!/bin/sh
poetry install --sync
```

The downside is that it also runs when you checkout (revert) a single file. That can be prevented by checking the 3rd argument, and only running when a branch is checked out:

```
#!/bin/sh
flag=$3
if [[ "$flag" -eq 1 ]];then
  poetry install --sync
fi
```

For a mono-repo you could create an invocation for every relative path as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
flag=$3
if [[ "$flag" -eq 1 ]];then
  echo "updating root project"
  poetry install --sync
  echo "updating subproject"
  poetry -C $(pwd)/sub-project-A install --sync
fi
```

Without the `$(pwd)` you (can) get the poetry error `relative path can't be expressed as a file URI`.

Comment: E.g. triggered when the pyproject.toml changed?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are dealth with

- Having a continuous integration service like Github Actions
- Have a pull request workflow
- Have a bot that automatically opens new pull request for updated dependencies

[See Dependabot by Github](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot).

Comment: Are any of those relevant for local installs? E.g. for a workflow where I pull changes from a repo and run code.

Comment: Yes, when configurd correctly you will only pull automatically updated code.